# Clarification about positive definition of prime numbers in book Douglas Hofstadter "Gödel, Escher, Bach: An eternal golden braid"

Tags: prime-numbers, formal-languages, formal-systems

I'm reading this book in Dutch. There is a part that keeps me puzzled. Maybe I don't fully understand (needing explanation) or suspect potential errors in the translation (needing verification). **Could anyone with an English copy help me in verifying? And if it's correct, please help me understand?**

---

At the end of Chapter 3, Hofstadter is setting up a formal system to define the prime numbers in a positive way. This in contrast to defining them in a negative way, i.e. saying that prime numbers are those that are not divisible numbers.

1. It starts with a formal system for producing statements about whether X is divisible by Y. Hofstadter uses a coding system with strings of dashes/hyphens, x is a string containing X dashes/hyphens (e.g. '---' represents the number 3). In my copy, he mentions a production rule as follows:

   - Dutch: "Als x NDD y een stelling is, dan ook **x NDD xy**." (NDD = niet
     deelbaar door)
   - My translation to English: "If x NDB y is a statement,
     then also **x NDB xy**." (NDB = not divisible by)

   I think this rule should read "**xy NDD/NDB y**" in the end, instead of "**x NDD/NDB xy**", to be useful in his system. Then, it could be used to produce all numbers X that are not divisible by number Y, from the axioms (all dash/hyphen strings of the form x NDD/NDB xy).
2. In the next paragraph, there is the following sentence:

   - Dutch: "We zouden graag een manier willen hebben om in de taal van het systeem te zeggen: 'het getal Z is delervrij tot **X**', waarmee we bedoelen dat Z niet deelbaar is door enig getal tussen 2 en **Z**."
   - My translation to English: "We would like an approach to say in the language of the system: 'the number Z is divisor-free up to **X**', by which we mean dat Z is not divisible by any number from 2 to **Z**."

   I think the sentence should read "(...) by any number from 2 to **X**." instead.
3. Then finally in the formal system to produce the strings representing prime numbers, I can't seem to derive that for example 3 is a prime number, i.e. whether P--- is valid. Using the production rules backwards, I'd need to prove that 3 is divisor-free up to 2. But this is impossible using the available rules. At the same time, I don't see the purpose of the first production rule that is mentioned, so maybe it is not correct.

   - Dutch: "Als z NDD -- een stelling is, dan ook -- NDD z."
   - My translation to English: "If z NDB -- is a statement, then also -- NDB z."

   What is the purpose of this rule? The axiom "x NDD/NDB xy" already leads to conclude that 2 is not divisible by any number larger than 2. What do we learn additionally from 2 not being divisible by 1 (if that's even valid)? Rather - I think - a rule like this would be more useful:

   - My suggestion for an alternative rule: "If z NDB -- is a statement, then also z DF --." (DF = divisor-free up to)

   Then at least, from 3 not divisible by 2, we could conclude that 3 has no divisors up to 2, leading eventually to 3 being a prime number.

Comment: No what it says is, "'the number Z is divisor-free up to **X**', by which we mean that Z is not divisible by any number from 2 to **Z**." I think the last Z should be an X instead.

Comment: I see - sorry...Yes, surely $Z$ divides $Z$. I think this is a typo on the letter, which has nothing to do with Dutch (so it is not a wrong translation but just a typo. You suspected "potential errors in the translation" ).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If that's the case also in the English version, how can we prove "-----------DND-----" (12 not divisible by 5) from the axiom and rule?

Comment: My 1979 edition, page 74: "Rule: if $x \text D \text N \text D y$ is a theorem, then so is $x \text D \text N \text D xy$

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well, it could be a typo during translation. I hope Hofstadter checked his typo's thoroughly. And there are the other - more important - issues also.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What does DND mean? What example is shown?

Comment: Does Not Divide. Axiom Schema (pag 73): $xy \text D \text N \text D x$. Example: 5 DND 2. Using the Rule above twice (page 74) it proves 5 DND 12.

Comment: Then the problem follows: "But 2 DND 5 is not a theorem." New Rules added...

Comment: Next step is "divisor-freeness": Rule: if −−DNDz is a theorem, then so is zDF−− meaning "if 2 Does Not Divide Z, then Z is *divisor-free* up to 2".

Comment: And Rule: if zDFx is a theorem and also x−DNDz is a theorem, then zDFx− is a theorem.

Comment: Final Rule: if $z- DFz$ is a theorem, then $Pz-$ is a theorem. And Axiom: $P--$, meaning "2 is prime".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks, so the error happened in translation. Because the English version talks about x Does-Not-Divide z, whereas Dutch is mirrored grammatically (z Not-Divisible-By x). And the rule "−−DNDz is a theorem, then so is zDF−−" has been completely messed-up. I should have asked for the English version for this early Christmas present... :-(

Answer (score 1):

1. In Hofstadter's original English, the operator which the Dutch translator translates to NDD is DND. This is to be understood as "does not divide". Perhaps you have mistaken the left-hand operand for the right-hand one and vice versa?
2. You are correct. This must be a mistake in the translation. The English says 'We would like to have a way of saying, in the language of the system, "the number $Z$ is *divisor-free* up to $X$", meaning that no number between 2 and $X$ divides $Z$.'
3. You are correct. This must be another mistake in the translation. The English indeed uses DF exactly as you suggest.